# Can't fine item Icon files in <projct_name>-Info.plist

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4

or should I just add row and name it as "Icon files"?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I find what should i do is just add a new row and name it "Icon files".